# Can't change default playback device on Windows 10

Tags: audio, windows-10, device-manager, playback

I changed the default playback device from speakers to headset, but sound is still coming from speakers.

[image]

In this case, the default device is headset, but as you can see, the green indicator shows that sound is coming from speakers.

This was working in the past, but a few days ago I noticed this.

Comment: I have this problem also, did you find a fix?

Comment: I didnt, sonetimes it work if you first stop music (close app) and then change device and the turn music on

Comment: Just Disable the Via HD Audio Speaker in the middle, it should work , and make sure the drivers are installed correctly for the logitech device , check device manager

Answer (score 2):

There's a known bug with Windows 10 and Via HD audio.

My report of it is [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/via-hd-audio-on-windows-10-not-switching-to/) (MS external site, might get on a freaking loop because of cookies... or die in a BSOD because why not). Long story short: It won't work flawlessly on Win10 as of today. Current status is: one might connect headphones and sound comes out of them but sound still comes out of speakers.

The default won't change from one to another. The recommendation is to remove any previous audio drivers and [update drivers to something that kinda works](http://download.viatech.com/) on Win10.

Comment: The link to your report seems to be broken.

Comment: @Guerrilla that site tends to have issues with old cookies. The link to the drivers stands, though.

Comment: looks like driver issue , because the hardware is not recognized correctly by windows he must check device manager , we shouldn't blame windows for every problem , sometimes it is driver for hardware is bad http://bit.ly/27cciI4

Comment: @mussdroid it IS indeed a driver issue. OS was released "assuring compatibility" but hardware providers (like Realtek / VIA / etc.) didn't release updates on time and we got stucked with BSODs and malfunctioning PCs. Thing is: what is an OS without proper drivers? There's some team work required to make it viable.

Comment: Microsoft can solve this easily , the need to create common platform so that hardware providers can easily access , push their latest drivers for specific hardware , when there is no common platform for this it is good otherwise  everybody doing their way so there are driver at multiple resources and with different version and then boom the hardware is not functioning properly

Comment: I'm having a similar issue that sounds like it might be related: I connect to a monitor, and the sound switches to that monitor (even if it is speakerless). I have my laptop speakers set as default device, but everytime I connect to a monitor (even a previously used monitor) it returns to using the monitor as playback device.